# Any alternative to using RODBC for R version 3.1.2?

Tags: r

I am unable to install package RODBC. I get an error.

```
install.packages("RODBC")

package ‘RODBC’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘RODBC’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using OS X Yosemite. I checked the CRAN Page http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html as of today there is no release available.

```
OS X Mavericks binaries:    r-release: not available
```